# CMake find_library can't find my library even with HINTS

Tags: cmake

I have the following code:

```
project(test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

set(PNG_DIR C:/Users/Kagami/.emscripten_cache/wasm/ports-builds/libpng)

find_library(PNG_STATIC_LIBRARY
  NAMES libpng.a
  HINTS ${PNG_DIR}
)

message(${PNG_DIR})
message(${PNG_STATIC_LIBRARY})
```

I have a file named `libpng.a` in that `PNG_DIR` directory but `find_library` still returns `-NOTFOUND`. What would be the possible reasons?

Comment: `find_path` works, not sure why not `find_library`.

Answer (score 3):

`find_library` will find a library that he can be used with the arch you use. So on your Windows it will not look for `.a` but for `.lib`.

But `find_path` just search a file doesn't matter if it's a real library or not.

From the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) :

> Each library name given to the NAMES option is first considered as a library file name and then considered with platform-specific prefixes (e.g. lib) and suffixes (e.g. .so). Therefore one may specify library file names such as libfoo.a directly. This can be used to locate static libraries on UNIX-like systems.

Answer (score 1):

The NAMES parameter to [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) specifies the library name, not the file name.

So in your case the correct command would be

```
find_library(PNG_STATIC_LIBRARY
  NAMES png
  HINTS ${PNG_DIR}
)
```

Note that you can give more than one name as arguments to the NAMES, in case the library ships under different names on the different platforms.

An additional complication here comes from the fact that on Windows we have two incompatible toolchains, MinGW and MSVC. If your library has a `.a` file ending, it was almost certainly compiled for the MinGW toolchain, so you will not be able to use it from a Visual Studio build. Here you would first need to recompile the library with the correct toolchain.

Comment: "The NAMES parameter to [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) specifies the library name, not the file name." - Not quite true. The documentation describes the actual meaning of NAMES parameter below: "Each library name given to the `NAMES` option is first considered as a library file name and then considered with platform-specific prefixes (e.g. `lib`) and suffixes (e.g. `.so`). Therefore one may specify library file names such as `libfoo.a` directly."